# Why in this factorial code (no recursion) the step is -1 instead of +1?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Why in this code for calculating factorial the step is -1, not +1?
How it calculates n = 0, if in the program we have only n < 0 and n > 0?

```
def factorial(n)
  if n < 0
    return nil
  end

  result = 1
  while n > 0
    result = result * n

    n -= 1
  end

  return result
end
```

Comment: `4! = 4*3*2*` or `2*3*4`. The author of this code decided to start at `4` (the argument `n`) and work down.

Comment: (Without code comments, nobody knows just why result is not initialised to `n`, followed by decrementing `n` and multiplying it into the result while `1 < n`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It calculates `n=0` because `result` is set to `1` by default. When `n` is `0`, the loop will not run (because `n` is not `> 0`), so the default value of `result` (which is `1`) will be returned.

It subtracts one each time so that it can count downward over all the numbers, so

> 5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1

If it added one each time it would be

> 5! = 5 * 6 * 7 * 8...

and so on. So not only would it be wrong but it would also be an infinite loop.

Comment: I see how 0! is set to 1 in your code but  why does 0! equal 1 anyway?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 That's how the factorial function is defined in math. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Definition

Comment: @sagarpandya82 That's an interesting question actually, but not one I know the answer to. I do know that mathematicians decided to define it that way, I just don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

The step is -1 so that you multiply together all the values of n * (n -1) * (n - 2) * ... * 1.  Since the multiplication starts at n and goes down, you want the step to be negative. (Alternatively, you *could* start at 1 and go up to n. In that case you would want the step to be +1. That's just not how this implementation works.)

The program still works for an input of 0 because the default is set to `result = 1` before the while loop. The body of the loop is skipped in that case.

Answer (score 2):

`1 * 2 * 3 == 3 * 2 * 1`, so arithmetically it doesn't matter whether you work your way up or down.  However, decrementing the argument `n` allows it to be used directly in calculating `result`, as opposed to basing the calculation on an additional separate variable which gets incremented until it hits `n`.

That said, it's still not a very ruby way of doing things.  I'd probably go with something like:

```
def factorial(n)
  n == 0 ? 1 : (1..n).inject(:*)
end
```

You also asked how your implementation calculates `factorial(0)` as 1.  If `n == 0` the `while n > 0` loop is never activated, so from your initialization `result = 1` you skip down to the `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the step is -1 and not +1 is because the while loop is going `while n > 0`. So if you were to do `n += 1`, you would have an infinite loop on your hands.

If you were to set up a for loop with an iterator, you could start the iterator and go until `iterator <= n`. In that case, you would want to do `iterator += 1`. But in this situation, we just need to multiply all the values from 1-n together, which is not sensitive to order. Because of that, it is simpler and less code to start at `n` and decrement it until it reaches zero. That is the reason for `n -= 1`.